# Protection circuit for fake-USB device

Tags: usb, protection, usb-device, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

I'm developing a set of sensor modules that connect to a controller board, that's also developed by me. Though the communication between controller and slaves is RS-485, I'd like to use a USB-C connector because it has some - as I believe unbeatable - advantages like being pretty, allowing hotplugging and also being relatively cheap.

Of course, people are going to plug proper USB devices/hosts in, so I need to make sure none of the devices involved take any damage.

My controller-slave connection consists of a 3.3V supply, GND and 4 RS-485 wires. So the main problem appears to be that my 3.3V will collide with the USB's 5V line and I came up with the below circuit to deal with that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqvzsN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is, that the op-amp turns off the 3.3V output whenever there is a voltage higher than 3.3V (plus some margin) applied externally to Vcc. The input is pulled high, so the output is off by default and therefore it's off even at the moment, a device is plugged in. In order to get supply voltage, my slaves will pull down Vcc.

I simulated the circuit with LTspice and found that it behaves like I expected, but I still wonder:

- Is such an approach legal / is there a general rule that prohibits the (mis)use of usb sockets for different purposes?
- A proper USB device connected to my controller does probably not operate at 3.3V. Is it still possible it takes damage?

Comment: it'll create confusion for others - you can be 100% confident of that

Comment: also body diode on the mosfet??

Comment: @PeteW I think, people will get used to get "confused" by USB-C sockets anyway: you never know whether it's a host, device, source or sink. You simply plug in and you'll see if it works. I'm planning to implement software-usb on the slave side later... Anyway, confusing the user is not my major concern

Comment: General rule == common sense not to reuse connectors with defined usage to something custom. Besides since it is an N channel FET it has a built in protection diode from source to drain so no matter how you control the FET the diode can still push out couple of amps of 3.3V with about 1V voltage drop.

Comment: and finally, what happens when the remote device is powered down? you would have conduction paths thru its ESD diodes, so you'd want to work out those scenarios carefully

Comment: @Justme I'm aware of the body diode, but I thought it wouldn't matter, because the output is pulled high. So the output should never be below 3.3V, except it gets shorted to a lower voltage (which I guess is not legal in USB either). Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for making that point! How would a device actually *power down*? ESD-protection diodes are typically from signal lines to Vcc and TVS diodes to ground. I don't see how that is relevant, could you enlighten me?

Comment: Just a standard thing to check, haven't thought through your scenario. When powered down, VDD is near GND, and every other line now has a diode that can sink current into the "low" VDD. In your case, the mosfet will put out something like 2.7V to the other guy's VDD... ...

Comment: @PeteW yeah, it's too easy to oversee body diodes and esd protection diodes. I'll have to think about that a little more I guess.

Comment: not saying it's certain to be an issue, just something that frequently causes surprises. And consider the reverse situation as well -- your device unpowered with live USB connection coming in (i.e. into negative input to op-amp)

Comment: @PeteW indeed that's sth I didn't think of. Would protecting this input with 1kOhm be sufficient? Something different: "not to reuse connectors with defined usage to something custom" -  that's very difficult when it comes to hotpluggability. After *a lot* of research I couldn't find any such connector which isn't part of a standard. Misusing an existing connector type seems to be the only possibililty (except for inventing a custom connector, which is too expensive for anyone but nasa).

Comment: Re: series resistor for OPA input -- Yes, something like that. Whatever value would limit current to an acceptable level in the scenario.   Re:  not to reuse connectors in general...  True, but of all of the possibilities, USB has to be the one that is most easy to mix up. And at least if I see a molex or D-SUB or SAC connector or something, I have reason to believe it's for some unique device, so I remember to think about what I'm doing. If you want to just make something work cheap, and it's just for you and nobody else, go ahead, but the general advice still applies

Comment: I don't see why you'd use a USB connector here. It seems to cause more problems than it's worth, honestly. It certainly wouldn't be allowed if you're going to sell this, though if you're just using it for your own thing that wouldn't be a problem. I'd consider a custom card-edge connector, personally; they're cheap and you can make them hot-pluggable by your own design pretty easily. Then you can just find an IDC card-edge connector, stick it on a ribbon cable, and be done with it.

Comment: Terminology nit-pick: You don't have RS485, you have RS422. RS485 is half-duplex over 2 wires while RS422 is full-duplex over 4 wires.

Comment: @brhans 4-wire 485 does exist. I believe the big difference is that 485 can have multiple devices responding on the bus (but that is not relevant here).

Comment: @brhans to my knowledge, the main difference is that RS-485 devices can set their output to high impedance to allow multiple slaves on the bus

Comment: Hi-Z-able outputs allows for multiple *Masters*, not multiple slaves.

Comment: @brhans Whenever one device is in control of the bus, all the others need to be high-Z. This applies to both master and slaves...